# Is it possible to match regex using variable?

Tags: regex, perl

Here is my code

```
my $filename = 'text.log';

my $items = "donkey";

open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename) or die "Cant open";

while (my $contents = <$fh>)
{
        print "$contents";

        if ( $items =~m/$contents/)             
             { print "Found $contents";}            
        else { print "NOTHING\n";}
}
```

Comment: When do you think you'll print `Found $contents`?  What you've written can run, but it requires caution; you probably won't ever see anything except NOTHING.  In particular, you're creating a new regex for each line — which probably isn't what you intend.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah creating new regex is my main purpose to get it from the text file. But it didnt match anything even it should.

Comment: Why would it ever match `donkey`?  The regex contains a newline which isn't in the `$items` string, so the regex will never match.  Even if you chomped the input line, you'd seldom have `$contents` matching `donkey`.  You could type `donkey`, or `d..key` or such like, but mostly, running text won't match `$items`.  If you[re writing a primitive `grep` that hunts for `donkey`, then you have the regex expression back to front: you need `if ($contents =~ m/$items/)` as the condition. The explanation of what you're trying to do should be in the question, along with simple sample input ([MCVE]!).

Comment: thanks everyone <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you'll need to remove the trailing newspace on each line (`$contents =~ s/\n$//;`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
my $filename = 'text.log';
my $items = "donkey";
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename) or die "Cant open";
while (my $contents = <$fh>) {
    print "$contents";
    $contents =~ s/\n$//;
    if ($items =~ m/$contents/) {
        print "Found $contents\n";
    } else {
        print "NOTHING\n";
    }
}
```

Test:

```
$ cat text.log 
test
ok
donk
$ ./test.pl 
test
NOTHING
ok
NOTHING
donk
Found donk
```

Comment: `chomp $contents;`